# why does $P(X) = X^3+X+1$ have at most 1 root in $F_p$?

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

why does $P(X) = X^3+X+1$ has at most 1 root in $F_p$ ?

I could fact check this on Sage for small values of $p$.

For example $p=5$ or $7$ or $19$; there is no root.

If $p = 11, 2$ is the only root.

If $p = 13, 7$ is the only root.

If $p = 17, 11$ is the only root.

I also realize that there can't be only 2 roots a1 and a2
because a3 = -(a1+a2) will be a root as well.

Comment: Given any monic integer polynomial $f$, there will be infinitely many primes for which $f$ splits into linear factors over $\Bbb F_p$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not true.

$3$ and $14$ are roots in $F_{31}$.

Comment: sorry for the stupid question. Should I delete this question ?

Comment: I don't think it was a stupid question

Comment: NB you also showed that 2 roots only is possible, contrarily to what i thought.

Comment: @Fagui Curtain That's true, but note that the root $X = 14$ has multiplicity $2$, so that $P$ splits into a product of linear factors modulo $31$. Comparing degrees shows that a cubic polynomial cannot have exactly two roots. on the other hand, if $F(X) \in \Bbb Z[X]$ does not have a double root then $F(X)$ only has a multiple root for finitely many modulo $p$, namely the prime factors of the discriminant $\Delta_F$. Computing gives $F_P = -31$, so $31$ is the only prime $p$ for which $P$ has exactly $2$ distinct roots.

Comment: thanks very much for this reminder !

Comment: Something went awry in typing up my previous comment. The second sentence should be, "...cannot have exactly two roots *counting multiplicity*," which I had intended to be the main point of the comment.

Comment: I should have proofread more carefully. The last sentence should be, "Computing gives $\Delta_P = -31$...".

Answer (score 3):

The primes other for which $x^3 + x + 1$ has three distinct roots are all those that can be represented by
$$  x^2 + xy + 8 y^2 $$
other than 31 itself

```
 31,     47,     67,    131,    149,    173,    227,    283,    293,    349,
379,    431,    521,    577,    607,    617,    653,    811,    839,    853,
857,    919,    937,    971,   1031,   1063,   1117,   1187,   1213,
```

The primes  for which $x^3 + x + 1$ has no roots are all those that can be represented by
$$  2x^2 + xy + 4 y^2 $$
other than 31 itself

```
  2,      5,      7,     19,     41,     59,     71,     97,    101,    103,
107,    109,    113,    157,    163,    191,    193,    211,    233,    257,
281,    307,    311,    317,    359,    373,    397,    419,    421,    439,
443,    467,    479,    503,    541,    547,    563,    593,    599,    659,
661,    683,    691,    701,    727,    733,    751,    769,    877,    887,
907,    977,    997,
```

The primes for which the cubic has one root are all odd primes $p$ such that Legendre symbol
$$ (-31|p) = -1 $$ Note that $31 \equiv 3 \pmod 4,$ so for any odd prime other than $31$ itself,
$$  (-31|p) =   (p|31)    $$

Comment: I asked an innocent question, and i find out that many people ask themselves these kind of questions, and more importantly find answers and meaning to it !!

Answer (score 2):

The first prime for which $x^3+x+1$ has $3$ distinct roots is $47$, where the roots are $24$, $34$ and $35$.
Hmm... it looks like the primes for which $x^3+x+1$ splits are [OEIS sequence A033221](https://oeis.org/A033221), the primes of the form $x^2 + 31 y^2$.

Comment: Yes, it is in a paper by Hudson and Williams

Comment: http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/Hudson_Williams_1991.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile, the numbers that can not be expressed with integers as
$$ 2x^2 + xy + 4 y^2 - z^3 - z  $$
are $\pm C_n,$ where the sequence of $C_n$ begins
$$  1, 869, 25171, 21118439, 611705641, 513220303709, 14865670462411,  $$
and obeys
$$ C_{n+4} = 24302 C_{n+2} - C_n. $$
Put another way, the numbers
$$ 27 C_n^2 + 4  $$
are of the form
$$  31 D_n^2 $$